# Calculating geometric based test statistic of a sample point

Tags: geometry, statistics

Hello this is my first question on this site, but I frequent in Stack Overflow and Ask Different.

I self-teaching statistics using the book [Statistical Methods: The Geometric Approach](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31tHVpX3ctL._SX313_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg) and I'm having a few difficulties applying geometry to statistical problems, specifically with calculating a test statistic as seen in the book's introduction. For the figure below, the author states that you can calculate the test statistic for a given sample - in this case the point $P(13,15)$ - by finding two lengths, A and B, and then finally taking the ratio $\frac{A}{B}$ to find your test statistic.

With the given example point, the author finds a ratio of: $\frac{14\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = 14$. I am stuck on figuring out how the author found the lengths for A and B. I tried obvious tricks like Pythagorean Theorem and Law of Sines but I was not able to get anywhere. A point in the right direction with an explanation would be wonderful.

Context to question: [context](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kl9OKThIerJCduu2ufaK4SGDXSbHxL9F/view?usp=sharing)

Figure in question:
[image: Figure in question]

Comment: Always best to put to put all pictures and figures in the question, if you can, rather than use links.

Comment: I apologize, I don’t have enough rep on this site to embed photos. I was forced to post links. Perhaps someone can edit it for me so the pictures are directly embedded in the question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that was a thing. I'll do it for you. One sec.

Comment: I can't find the relevant info in the book (I don't own a copy) nor can I find a pdf after a minute or so of trying, sadly, but perhaps someone has a copy. This seems like a context issue. If you put a link to a picture of the whole page and any other relevant book stuff, I'll put that in for you, too. Or you could just quote the book directly.

Comment: I actually own the PDF, but I'm not sure if I'm "allowed" to upload the entire text. I have 4 pages that provide context to the problem, how would you suggest I upload it?

Comment: Hmmm... that is just a bit too long to upload here, I imagine. I'm honestly not sure what to do at this point. Perhaps link to them in the body of the question.

Comment: Okay, I went ahead and did that.

Comment: I admit I find the text a bit hard to follow, as I am not a statistician. I *think* the line having length $14\sqrt{2}$ is the $45$-degree angled line drawn until it and the point (13,15) form a line perpendicular to it... I thought the text would clear things up, but it does not (not for me anyhow). I'm sure someone will come along and help.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I'm not the only one who's confused. I appreciate the help with formatting!

Comment: Happy to help. And welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found an answer to my question.

Considering the vector, $v=[13\;15]^T$, which is represented in the 2 space figure in the question as $P(13,15)$, the value of A and B can be solved like so:

- $A=14\sqrt{2}$ is found by solving for the length of the projection of $v$ onto the unit vector $U_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[1\;1]^T$: $$A=v.U_1=\frac{13+15}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{28}{\sqrt{2}}=14\sqrt{2} $$
- $B=\sqrt{2}$ is found by solving for the length of the projection of $v$ onto the unit vector $U_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[-1\;1]^T$: $$B=v.U_2=\frac{-13+15}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2} $$

In both of these values, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[1\;1]^T$ is the unit vector at $45^\circ$ to the x-axis and y-axis - the equiangular line between the two axes. The vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[-1\;1]^T$ is the perpendicular vector to the unit vector of the equiangular line.